# Angular 4: List doesn't update on replacement of item in backing array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I'm using Angular 4 (ES 6), and I have an issue.  I have an array that is powering a datatable.  When I add and remove items from the array, the datatable behaves accordingly.  But when I replace an item, i.e

```
 const indexOfOld = this.modelList.indexOf(oldThing);
 this.modelList[indexOfOld] = value;
```

I don't see my list/datatable updating. I know in other UI centric techs, you can kick the VM and get it to redraw (Flex -> invalidateDisplayList).

Is there a way to signal to Angular 4 (ES 6) that it needs to refresh the datatable/list?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where are you modifying the array?

Comment: Can you provide the code that creates the datatable? I'm pretty sure there's a rerender() method that you can call on your table instance when you replace an item, but it's hard to tell without any context.

Comment: @StephenR.Smith I'm using the data-table found here.  https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable

Comment: @Dummy I'm modifying the array in my Angular component `@Component.

Comment: What is the shape of each element in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to get the ngx-datatable (https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable) to refresh after updating the backing array, nor was I able to get it to refresh after calling

```
cd.markForCheck()
```

However, I was able to get the table to update after assigning the values of the new model to the old one.

```
    else if(oldBatchProcess){
      value.creationDateFormatted = this.datePipe.transform(value.creationDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a');
      const indexOfOld = this.batchProcesses.indexOf(oldBatchProcess);
      this.batchProcesses[indexOfOld] = value;
      Object.assign(oldBatchProcess, value);
    }
```